# C# DateTimePicker, how can I detect events when up-down button was clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Well I surely understand how OnValueChanged works. But I need to detect the up-down button, SPECIFICALLY, because I have a timer running back to increase the DateTimePicker automatically.
If timer is stopped in 'OnValueChanged', it just stops automatically. I just want the timer to stop only when up-down button was clicked, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "up-down" button? You can also see all available events on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=net-5.0#events in the `Events` section

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just disable typing in the picker by doing something like:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

This way the user would only be able to change the value using the Up / Down buttons.